# MacOS VSCode git only works when started code under sudo

Tags: git, macos, visual-studio-code

MacOS Big Sur (11.2), VSCode v1.53.1.

I have X-code installed. All these staffs started after I installed it.
I did `xcode-select --install` and did `sudo xcodebuild -license accept`.
git was installed by `brew install git`.

```
% git --version
git version 2.30.0
```

```
% where git
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/bin/git
```

```
% which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

VSCode settings.json:

```
{
    "git.path": "/usr/local/bin/git"
}
```

when I start code like `sudo code` - it works, but when I start it in normal mode I see this:

[image]

`code --disable-extensions` - didn't help

Any git-related command from command pallet raised this error:

[image]

When I click on "clone repository..." on Wellcome screen, I see this error:

[image]

But, as I said, everything works fine when I start code under sudo.

I spent days trying to solve this issue, searching a lot, but still have no clue how to solve it. If anybody would help with that I'll be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, there was a problem in `.zshenv` file.
Somehow there was line like this:

> export TMPDIR=/tmp:$TMPDIR

And when some program tried to use the temp folder, this folder becomes unavailable, and the program has failed.
The side effects of this stuff were also failed git and a lot of other programs.
The solution was simple: just remove this line from `.zshenv`